# How to read a file in Python

Tags: python, file

I have a file on my computer called test. It's a .py file. I only have 2 things in the file.

```
'Is this working?

"Probably not."
```

When I try to read it I get this:

```
>>>t = open('test')

>>>t

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='test' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

>>>t.read()

''
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm a pretty new at this. I have some ideas on what it could be, but I can't find any answers online. Thanks in advance.

> Thank you all for the answers! I just opened up a new file and printed "f.readlines" and it worked. I also think my problem was I was using IDLE, which I've come to notice doesn't really work that well with some commands, for some reason. Either way, thank you all for the help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, what the issue is and what you've tried already to solve the issue. Also, consider posting relevant code snippets and have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Comment: `"test"` and `"test.py"` are both valid file names. Do  you also have a file just named `"test"`?

Comment: You're basically doing it right. Are you getting errors? Or is `t.read()` not giving you the content of the file?

Comment: It seems that you are using a Windows system where your 3 letter extension is not shown. I assume that since you said it is a .py file.

Answer (score 1):

General syntax to read the file in python is 
oparend =open("filename","filemode")

Basic file modes are: r,w,a,r+,w+,a+, rb, wb

You can read the file in following modes 
r,a+,w+,r+
But criteria is different in different modes.
For example file with name of file.txt
Can read by the following syntax
F=open("file.txt",'r')
If you don't mention any thing by default in the read mode

After the opening a file you can read entire data of the file by using 
F.Readlines()
note : 
You shouldn't open the file in W+ mode  when ever you want to read the previous existing data, It just clear the entire file.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a Windows system where the file extension is not shown. I assume that since you said it is a .py file. In your open statement, try using "test.py" instead of "test".

```
cat test.py
'Is this working?

"Probably not."

$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> t = open("test.py")
>>> t
<open file 'test.py', mode 'r' at 0x7f2b7ab93540>
>>> t.read()
'\'Is this working?\n\n"Probably not."\n
```

Comment: `py` is a *two* letter extension. To be exact, the number of characters in the file extension does not matter at all.

Answer (score 0):

By default on Windows, the file extension is hidden. Make sure you're using the *full* filename, extension included, as visible in the ribbon:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhqOQ.png

```
with open('test.py') as f:
  print(f.readlines())
```

That should print out

```
'Is this working?

"Probably not."
```